# React-Navigation conditionals in navigationOptions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How would I use an if statement to return a different icon if I have an unread message?
Or would I not use an if statement? Maybe setting the state on something? Not sure what the best route to take is here.

```
static navigationOptions = {
tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
  focused 
  ? <Icon name="ios-mail" 
    style={styles.activeIconRight} 
    />
  : <Icon name="ios-mail"
    style={styles.inActiveIconRight}
    />
),
```

}

```
updateUnread = () => {
    if (this.state.unread == true) {
      this.props.navigation.setParams({otherParam: 'NEW'})
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.setParams({otherParam: ' '})
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an icon to indicate that it is unread (called `ios-mail-new` here), then.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
      if(params.otherParams === 'NEW') {
        <Icon name="ios-mail-new" 
         style={[styles.activeIconRight, focused && styles.inActiveIconRight]} 
        />
      }
      else {
        <Icon name="ios-mail" 
         style={[styles.activeIconRight, focused && styles.inActiveIconRight]}
        />
      }
),
```

Key here is obtaining `navigation` as a passed in param.

Comment: Tried this a long time ago, just forgot to respond. this does work

Comment: could you please help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62035448/react-navigation-how-to-set-initialparams-for-screen-based-on-condition