# React-navigation: How to set initialParams for screen based on condition?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have `BottomTabsNavigator` as part of `StackNavigator`.

When I launch the app, I need to pass `initialParams` in Home tab based on a condition in `BottomTabsNavigator`.

Apparently, BottomTabsNavigator is rendered once only and initialParams always sends default value instead of new value based on condition.

```
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
      title: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: 'home-outline',
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    }}

    initialParams={{ 'tappedNotification1': notificationOpened }} // <---- here I want to send notificationOpened  value when its value is updated, 
  />
```

I use below hook to update value for `notificationOpened` to true (which needs to be sent as `initialParams` for Home screen.

```
    function onOpened(openResult) {
      navigation.navigate('NotificationDetailsScreen', {
        ...openResult.notification.payload.additionalData,
        tappedNotification: true,
        isRead: false,
      });

      setNotificationOpened(true);
    }
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', onOpened);

    return () => {
      OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', onOpened);
    }; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, [navigation, user]);
```

**Updated Comment :**

@Guruparan Giritharan
I did exactly the same using your suggestion. its a little hard to explain but please stay with me.

In my `BottomTabsNavigator` I declare a state 'notificationOpened' with intialValue false and pass it to `NotificationContext.Provider` value. which is accessible in Home.

`Home` screen has a modal popup which should display based on the value received in context's `notificationOpened` `(modal should display when notificationOpened is false)`

in my case, I update `notificationOpened` value from `BottomTabsNavigator` to true so modal won't display.

but `Home` receives `false` from context at the beginning and show the modal. 
Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You can use context, something like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61913658/react-native-navigation-5-passing-updated-component/61920816?noredirect=1#comment109526305_61920816

Comment: Thanks. in the example context is created and used on same page. in my case I have to pass that to Home component and retrieve its value there. How can I pass that value from BottomTabsNavigator to Home screen without declaring it again on Home.

Comment: I have created another snack here illustrating my issue. I have created Context in App.js and  need to use the value passed from App.js in Home.js https://snack.expo.io/@rikinshah23/tabs-with-context

Comment: You just have to put the context in a separate file, check my answer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i updated my comment in question itself cause its bit long.

Comment: The notificationOpened is part of the state right ? did you console log the value in home screen ?

Comment: notificationOpened  is part of state. I did console log in Home it says false, false, then starts being true for subsequent render

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214760/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-newdeveloper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation recommends using context or some sort of store like redux to update the count variables on the tabs. You have a similar requirement.
You can look at this sample to get an idea to do that.

First you will need to create a context file

```
const NotificationContext = React.createContext(0);

export default NotificationContext;
```

And the file which contains your tabs

```
const MyTabs = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <NotificationContext.Provider value={count}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>{count}</Text>
        <Button title="count" onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)} />
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ title: 'My home' }}/>
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} options={{ title: 'My home 2' }}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </View>
    </NotificationContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And the Homescreen file can read and update itself using the 'usecontext'

```
import NotificationContext from './NotificationContext';

export function HomeScreen() {
  const count = React.useContext(NotificationContext);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{count}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

This sample is based on the snack you provided.
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/tabs-with-context

Comment: I was able to do it, using useMemo hook, it is really useful for optimization to prevent unwanted renders. that lead me right direction.